# 'LIKE' or 'SOUNDEX' statement in Key-Value type NoSQL databases

Tags: sql, database, nosql

Friends, Romans and countrymen\women.

I'm researching NoSQL at the moment and have question that has sprung from my reading of [this](https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-main-differences-between-the-four-types-of-NoSql-databases-KeyValue-Store-Column-Oriented-Store-Document-Oriented-Graph-Database) article.

For Key-Value pair databases, given that the key is the only thing the *system* knows about the stored data and that key is derived "exactly like a hash table", how would you get a close match as in a LIKE or SOUNDEX? e.g. what if a user supplied the customer name of 'JENNY MORTON' and there was a business rule to return 'JENNY MORTONSEN'. From my understanding of hash tables, the key generated between the two names would be wildly different.

Comment: In the case of SOUNDEX, just store the SOUNDEX code along with the rest of the data so you can search by it later.

Comment: +Jordan...thanks. I'm trying to get used to this whole NoSQL and "application level" data integrity thing so any help you give is most welcome.